# Will deleting a photo on device, also delete the synced photos on Google?

Tags: storage, photos

My SD card and internal storage are full, and I want to free up some space. Is it safe to delete photos if the photos show that they are being synced to my Google account?

Answer (score 2):

- Google Photos synchronize your photos to your online storage (your online storage is limited to 10Gb if you choose synchronizing the original size of the photos ,and unlimited if you choose the high quality upload size , this setting can be edited under `Photos >> settings >> backup and sync >> upload size` ) now when Photos app synchronize you photos you end up with two copies, one on your local storage (sdcard) and the other one on your google photo storage so deleting the local version of the photo will not delete the one on your google Photos online storage.
- **However** if you had chosen the high quality option under the app's settings the app will not synchronize the original size of the photo
  but it will re-size it and then upload it so in this case you have
  two copies of the photos one with the original size on your SDcard
  and one re-sized on the server deleting the local copy will make
  you lose your original photo but your re-sized photo will still be on
  the server.
- Saving space on SD cards is one of the purpose of Google sync photo.